# Find a text in an XML file and output an element

Tags: python, xml, search

```
<data>
<number>
1
</number>
<text>
abc def
</text>
<number>
2
</number>
<text>
fhi jklmn
</text>
</data>
```

I would like to write a Python program which searches a given text in the XML file and outputs a corresponding element.

For example, in the above code, if 'jkl' is given, I want an output '2', and 'abc' is given, I want '1.'

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ xml.etree.ElementTree  find() and findall()

Comment: Add what did you tried and so we can help you to complete that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeautifulSoup to navigate XML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<data>
<number>
1
</number>
<text>
abc def
</text>
<number>
2
</number>
<text>
fhi jklmn
</text>
</data>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')
text = input('Please input your text : ')
t = soup.find(lambda t: False if t.name != 'text' else text in t.string)
if t:
    number = t.findPrevious('number').text.strip()
    print('Text {} found, the number is {}'.format(text, number))
else:
    print('Text {} not found'.format(text))
```

This will input user for a string and tries to find the string in `<text>` tags. If it is found, it will print value contained in `<number>`.

Example:

```
Please input your text : abc
Text abc found, the number is 1
```

EDIT:

For searching all tags for given string, not just `<text>` change the `find()` function to:

```
t = soup.find(lambda t: False if not t.string else text in t.string)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. Actually the text I'm looking for does not have to be in the element 'text.' It can be anywhere in the XML file. May I delete the condition 'False if t.name != 'text' ?

Comment: I tried something like     t = soup.find(lambda t: text in t.string)  but it does not work

Comment: @user67275 I updated my answer. For searching all tags you do `t = soup.find(lambda t: False if not t.string else text in t.string)`